# Issue with Union Sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, union, union-all

I'm attempting to use a union sub query to get the results for a couple different queries. What I'm looking to do is select all the players who hit a home run in the 2014 season, create a home run count for each player and find the average pitch speed of each home run. I'm also attempting to break things down by pitch type, my current code and result are as follows:

```
Select output.Batter_Name,
output.Qty,
output.speed,
output.avg_Speed,
output.break,
output.Type_Pitch,
    Output.CH_Qty,
    Output.CH_Pitch,
    Output.Ch_Speed,
    Output.CH_Avg_speed,
    Output.CH_Break,
    Output.CH_Type_Pitch

From(
SELECT 
    count(gameday.atbats.event) as Qty,
    gameday.batters.name_display_first_last as Batter_Name,
    gameday.pitches.type as Pitch,
    gameday.pitches.start_speed as speed,
    avg(gameday.pitches.start_speed) as avg_speed,
    avg(gameday.pitches.break_length) as Break,
    gameday.pitches.Pitch_type as Type_Pitch,
    "0" as CH_Qty,
    "0" as CH_Pitch,
    "0" as Ch_Speed,
    "0" as CH_Avg_speed,
    "0" as CH_Break,
    "0" as CH_Type_Pitch

FROM


    gameday.atbats
        JOIN
    gameday.pitches ON gameday.atbats.num = gameday.pitches.gameAtBatID
        AND gameday.pitches.gamename = gameday.atbats.gamename
        INNER JOIN
    gameday.batters ON gameday.atbats.batter = gameday.batters.ID
        AND gameday.atbats.gamename = gameday.batters.gameName
        INNER JOIN
    gameday.pitchers ON gameday.atbats.pitcher = gameday.pitchers.ID
        AND gameday.atbats.gamename = gameday.pitchers.gamename
WHERE
    (gameday.atbats.event = 'Home Run')
        AND gameday.pitches.type = 'x'
        and gameday.pitches.Pitch_type = 'FF'
 group by gameday.batters.name_display_first_last

 UNION ALL

 SELECT 
    "0" as Qty,
    gameday.batters.name_display_first_last as Batter_Name,
    "0" as Pitch,
    "0" as Speed,
    "0" as Avg_speed,
    "0" as Break,
    "0" as Type_Pitch,
    count(gameday.atbats.event) as CH_Qty,
    gameday.pitches.type as CH_Pitch,
    gameday.pitches.start_speed as CH_speed,
    avg(gameday.pitches.start_speed) as CH_avg_speed,
    avg(gameday.pitches.break_length) as CH_Break,
    gameday.pitches.Pitch_type as CH_Type_Pitch


FROM


    gameday.atbats
        JOIN
    gameday.pitches ON gameday.atbats.num = gameday.pitches.gameAtBatID
        AND gameday.pitches.gamename = gameday.atbats.gamename
        INNER JOIN
    gameday.batters ON gameday.atbats.batter = gameday.batters.ID
        AND gameday.atbats.gamename = gameday.batters.gameName
        INNER JOIN
    gameday.pitchers ON gameday.atbats.pitcher = gameday.pitchers.ID
        AND gameday.atbats.gamename = gameday.pitchers.gamename
WHERE
    (gameday.atbats.event = 'Home Run')
        AND gameday.pitches.type = 'x'
        and gameday.pitches.Pitch_type = 'CH'
 group by gameday.batters.name_display_first_last
 ) as Output

 group by Output.Batter_name
```

A Sample of my results are below:

```
Batter_Name, Qty, speed, avg_Speed, break, Type_Pitch, CH_Qty, CH_Pitch, Ch_Speed, CH_Avg_speed, CH_Break, CH_Type_Pitch
A.J. Pollock    1     89     90      4.3      FF        0        0          0           0          0         0
Aaron Hicks     0      0      0      0        0         1        X          83          83         6          CH
```

The first player, Ellis shows that he had one home run on a FF, and zero on a CH. The 2nd player,Peirzynski, had 0 home runs on a FF, but 1 on a CH. The issue is that I know these players had home runs on both types of pitches, but the query is only one or the other, not both. My intended results are something like this:

```
Batter_Name, Qty, speed, avg_Speed, break, Type_Pitch, CH_Qty, CH_Pitch, Ch_Speed, CH_Avg_speed, CH_Break, CH_Type_Pitch
A.J. Pollock    1     89     90      4.3      FF        2        X          84           82         3.2          CH
Aaron Hicks     4     90     91      2.5      FF        1        X          83           83          6           CH
```

I'm thinking the issue has to be my setting some fields to 0, kind of like a place holder, but i cant seem to find a workable solution that gets me the results I want.

Comment: Most RDBMS (quite sensibly) won't let you reference unaggregated columns in a grouped query unless the results are grouped on those columns.  As a performance optimisation, MySQL *does* allow this—but is very clear in the documentation that the results are indeterminate: after all, you have not specified from which record from the group should it return a value, and it makes no guarantees over which will be used.

Comment: In short, MySQL is crazy-bananas. Make sure that if you are aggregating in your SELECT clause (sum, max, avg, count, etc..) that every other Non-Aggregated field/alias is down in your GROUP BY otherwise you are going to get crazy nonsense returned. Any other RDBMS would, rightly, give you a big fat error. MySQL is Crazy Bananas for this, BTW.

Comment: @JNevill Your suggestion sorta worked. It produces 2 lines for each player, one line for FF home runs, and one line for CH home runs. I would like to group these to one line for each player.

Comment: Then you'll have to remove whatever field it is that is giving "FF" or "CH" from the SELECT and GROUP BY clause. The DB will always aggregate to the lowest level of granularity, in your case, the type of Home Run.